# Generating an XML Sitemap in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel application that is still in the development stages. I am currently trying to generate a sitemap for the application using Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator but my code isn't working. This is my sitemap code in a file called GenerateSiteMap.php:

```
<?php

use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

class GenerateSiteMap
{
    public function generateSite()
    {
        $generator = SitemapGenerator::create('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
        return $generator;
    }
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors when I run it, it just doesn't do anything. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe a file permission issue? Other than that, enable error reporting and share the error messages.

Comment: php.ini says display_errors is on. There are no errors when I run the file

Answer (score 1):

If your file is at public folder you need to add `public_path`

```
$generator = SitemapGenerator::create('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')->writeToFile(
public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```

otherwise it might be a permission issue

Comment: It is in the project root. I added public_path and it's still not doing anything. I feel like if it was a permission issue I would get some sort of error but I don't.